# optimal thread pool size in tizen

Tags: c, multithreading, tizen

I have developed a partial in TIZEN project using 6-7 thread(pthread) which mostly does network i/o. Now my requirement is changing. If I keep my design it might require 50+ threads eventually. Or I can change the design and keep a event queue and distribute all the task of the threads and make it work using 8+ threads. So I was wondering what are the optimal number of thread for TIZEN.

It is to be noted that atleast 15+% of the time threads are idle.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to answer an optimization question is to *try* something, generate some profiling data, then try something different. Repeat until you notice a trend or find a configuration you are satisfied with.

Due to the cross-platform nature of Tizen, and not knowing much about the nature of your project requirements or what devices it will be run on, it is hard to say anything specific.